# Do I have to be an expat to ask a passport-related question?

Tags: discussion

Do I need to be an expat in order to inquire about an ancestral passport?

Comment: If the question arises because you are an expat you should post it here. If it is to do with travel then please post to the travel stackexchange site

Comment: As you have included the Netherlands tag, there are many questions and answers here regarding Dutch citizenship. Do a 'Search on Expatriates' (at the very top next to StackExchange) with those terms, or by clicking on this https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/search?q=dutch+citizenship

Comment: We've had a lot of questions on this site about Dutch nationality. If you can't get what you need from those questions, you can ask. The basic principle in the Netherlands is that there is no way of getting Dutch nationality directly from any ancestor other than a parent, so if you have a Dutch ancestor you need to be able to show that every person connecting you to that ancestor was also Dutch from birth. The rules for passing Dutch nationality to a child are complicated and have changed over the years, as have the rules for automatic loss of Dutch nationality by dual nationals.

Comment: Just delete this question and ask your passport related one.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, asking questions about whether you have a specific nationality and how you can obtain a passport in that nationality is welcome here, even in case you are personally not an expat. Any questions about having a different nationality than the one you are living in is also welcome.

Do note that we already have a few questions regarding Dutch nationality, and it might also have been answered as well: https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/search?q=dutch+citizenship